# Sort list of lists of tuples of class instances by min attribute value

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have looked through many related questions but I haven't found one that specifically deals with the following problem. I have a list of lists, where each list contains tuples. Those tuples consist of two items, both class instances, that have an `id` attribute. I want to sort the *outer* list only, so that it is sorted in such a way that the sublists are ranked according to the minimal values of the attributes of the first item of all tuples in that sublist, and second by the minimal values of the attributes of the second item of all tuples.

This sounds more complex than it is, so here is an example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Char:
    id: int


l = [
    [(Char(1), Char(2)), (Char(2), Char(3))],
    [(Char(4), Char(2)), (Char(5), Char(3))],
    [(Char(0), Char(0))],
    [(Char(-1), Char(1))],
    [(Char(3), Char(-1))],
]
```

To reiterate: every sublist contains tuples that contain two `Char`s, which all have an `id`. These are always sequential: you can see that the first item of the first tuple is 1 and the first item of the second tuple is 2. Those sublists should be sorted by the min value of the first items and then the min values of the second items of tuples.

The expected output, then, is as follows:

```py
l = [
    [(Char(-1), Char(1))],
    [(Char(0), Char(0))],
    [(Char(1), Char(2)), (Char(2), Char(3))],
    [(Char(3), Char(-1))],
    [(Char(4), Char(2)), (Char(5), Char(3))],
]
```

-1 is the smallest value of all first items in the tuples, so that list has to come first.

The following works, but I am not sure if there is a better, more DRY/efficient way to do this:

```py
l.sort(key=lambda sub: (min([w[0].id for w in sub]),
                        min([w[1].id for w in sub])))
```

Comment: Maybe `l.sort(key=lambda sub: (sub[0][0].id, sub[0][1].id))`?

Comment: Terminology note: these aren't tuples of *classes*. They are tuples of `Char` *instances*. This matters because classes in Python are first-class objects, you *can* have a tuple of classes, e.g. `(int, str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might make `Char` class instances comparable using `order=True`:

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class Char:
    id: int
```

as they will get `__lt__` method they will be directly usable in `min` and `sort`. Then you might do:

```
l = [
    [(Char(-1), Char(1))],
    [(Char(0), Char(0))],
    [(Char(1), Char(2)), (Char(2), Char(3))],
    [(Char(3), Char(-1))],
    [(Char(4), Char(2)), (Char(5), Char(3))],
]
l.sort(key=lambda sub:[min(i) for i in zip(*sub)])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[(Char(id=-1), Char(id=1))], [(Char(id=0), Char(id=0))], [(Char(id=1), Char(id=2)), (Char(id=2), Char(id=3))], [(Char(id=3), Char(id=-1))], [(Char(id=4), Char(id=2)), (Char(id=5), Char(id=3))]]
```

zip-unpacking construct transpose your subelement so it is possible to use `min` on corresponding elements therefore `lambda` for each sub will return `list` with smallest element from those occupying first place in tuples, smallest elemnt from those occupying second place and so on. Keep in mind this solution will work different than your if there are tuples with more than 2 elements and it assumes all tuples in each sublist have exactly equal number of elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot use an ordered dataclass (due to other things in the class), but that is just a small thing to solve. So apart from the zip, which allows for large tuples than my fixed-to-two example, I guess our solutions are in fact identical. I was thinking that `operator` had something built-in that could do things more efficiently than looping and min'ing. But it seems not.

Comment: @BramVanroy if requirements do not dictate you to use `dataclass` you might consider replacing `Char` with normal `class`, featuring `__lt__` magic method comparing on `id`s

Answer (score -1):

I came up with the following:

```
In [5]: l.sort(key=lambda sub: sum(ch.id for t in sub for ch in t))

In [6]: l
Out[6]: 
[[(Char(id=0), Char(id=0))],
 [(Char(id=-1), Char(id=1))],
 [(Char(id=3), Char(id=-1))],
 [(Char(id=1), Char(id=2)), (Char(id=2), Char(id=3))],
 [(Char(id=4), Char(id=2)), (Char(id=5), Char(id=3))]]

In [7]:
```

Comment: That is incorrect. Look at my "expected output". There is nothing that needs to be summed either...

Comment: yep, sorry, misunderstood the question